# Regex: Find all words separated by signs + - = (Search and Replace)

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, regex

I have this scenario:

`data-cycle-center-horz=true other words`

`data-cycle-caption=".custom-captions"  other words`

`data-cycle-caption-template="{{slideNum}}  other words`

`before words .data-cycle-caption-template="{{slideNum}}  other words`

`.data-cycle-caption-template="{{slideNum}}  other words`

So I need to find all words separated by signs `- = . "{`

I made a regex for NOTEPAD++ to search and delete those words that have signs before and after (the whole string) without the other words, but not very good:

SEARCH:  `(?!\w+[-."={])`

REPLACE: (leave empty)

The expected result should be:

`other words`

`other words`

`other words`

`before words  other words`

`other words`

Comment: What are expected results for all these examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:^|[+=."{}-]+)(?:\w+[+=."{}-]+)+\h*`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:             # start non capture group
  ^             # beginning of line
 |              # OR
  [+=."{}-]+    # 1 or more + = . " { } -
)               # end group
(?:             # start non capture group
  \w+           # 1 or more word character
  [+=."{}-]+    # 1 or more + = . " { } -
)+              # end group, may appear 1 or more times
\h*             # 0 or more horizontal spaces
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

<strike>What I am reading from your question is that you want to basically match all the words, but not the seperating special characters, right?</strike>

`[^-=."{}\r\n]+` should do the trick. It will match everything that is not your special characters `- = . "{` or a line break.

You can build and test regex with an online tool like [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

**Update**
The following regex removes the words as you described, as well as trailing whitespaces: `([^\s]+[-=."{}\r\n][^\s]+\s*)+`

I successfully tested it on your example:
*Before*:

```
data-cycle-center-horz=true other words

data-cycle-caption=".custom-captions"  other words

data-cycle-caption-template="{{slideNum}}  other words

before words .data-cycle-caption-template="{{slideNum}}  other words

.data-cycle-caption-template="{{slideNum}}  other words
```

After:

```
other words

other words

other words

before words other words

other words
```

Comment: works, But I also want to match and delete those words from the text. Doesn't work the search and replace (with empty). Can U make a Search and Replace for your regex?

Comment: That's weird, notepad++ replace works fine for me with this regex and the example text you provided.

Did you make sure to tick "Regular expression" in the Replace -> Search mode window?

Comment: works, match, but the replace does not work. I want to delete those words and the signs

Comment: You want to delete the matched words and the special characters? That would mean you delete everything. I am not quite sure I understand what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: delete only those words that have signs

Comment: Do you mean you want to delete every string that contains words seperated by the special characters? So if `data-cycle-center-horz=true` appears in the text, you want to delete the whole string?

Comment: the whole string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97483/discussion-between-user9211114-and-just-me).

Answer (score 1):

This is written in Python, It loads your test data from a file "data.txt" in same directory

[Install Python](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.4/python-3.7.4.exe)

```
import os, re

path = "./data.txt"
if os.path.isfile(path): #use local leader file
    oFile = open(path)
    strFile = oFile.read() #get old leaders
    oFile.close()
else:
    print("File Not Found")

def replace(line):
    for i in line:
        if ( i == '-' or i == '=' or i == '.' or i == '"' or i == '{' or i == '}'):
            line = line.replace(i,"\n")#Delete \n and replace it with xyz to see
    return line

lines = strFile.split("\n")
for line in lines:

    answer = replace(line)

    print(answer)
```

**data
cycle
center
horz
true
data
cycle
caption
custom
captions
data
cycle
caption
template
slideNum**